# ejs <%- body %> body is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have a body that I want to connect to the main template. But unfortunately `<%- body %>` is not working, and returning `undefined`. I've tried `include()`, include `file.ejs`, directly path. However, that still didn't work, so I'm not sure what to do. Here's my code:

---

```
> app.js

var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
console.clear();

// EJS //
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/mvc/views"));

// SRC FOLDER PERMISSION //
app.use('/src', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src')));

// MODULES //
var controller = require(path.join(__dirname, "/mvc/controller/controller"));

// USING CONTROLLER MODULE //
app.use("/", controller);

app.listen(8080);
```

---

```
> mvc/controller/controller.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render("template");
}
router.get("/", module.exports.index);

module.exports = router;
```

---

```
> mvc/views/template.ejs

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid px-0 h-100">
        <%-body%>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

```
> mvc/views/home.ejs

<nav class="h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-center">
    <div class="line w-100">
        <span class="d-block"></span>
        <span class="d-block"></span>
    </div>
</nav>
```

---

```
> result

ReferenceError: C:\laragon\www\galeri-uygulamasi\mvc\views\template.ejs:18
    16| <body>

    17|     <div class="container-fluid px-0 h-100">

 >> 18|         <%-body%>

    19|     </div>

    20| </body>

    21| 


body is not defined
    at eval (C:\laragon\www\galeri-uygulamasi\mvc\views\template.ejs:10:16)
    at template (C:\laragon\www\galeri-uygulamasi\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:691:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\laragon\www\galeri-uygulamasi\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\laragon\www\galeri-uygulamasi\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (C:\laragon\www\galeri-uygulamasi\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\laragon\www\galeri-uygulamasi\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\laragon\www\galeri-uygulamasi\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\laragon\www\galeri-uygulamasi\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\laragon\www\galeri-uygulamasi\node_modules\express-ejs-layouts\lib\express-layouts.js:77:18)
    at module.exports.index (C:\laragon\www\galeri-uygulamasi\mvc\controller\controller.js:5:9)
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong? Any help would definitely be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need `res.render('home')` and not `res.render('template')`

Comment: it did not work but i tried this and worked: res.render('layout'), because module wants a file named 'layout' from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have a better solution for you.**
**Try this :**

1. *First change the 'template.ejs' file name to 'layout.ejs'. Because express-ejs-layouts will look for layout.ejs inside youre views folder.*
2. *Inside home.ejs add <%- contentFor('body') %> at top of youre code.*
3. *Now you can render youre home.ejs with it's layout.*

   ```
   // >mvc/controller/controller.js
   module.exports.index = function(req, res) {
       res.render("home"); 
   }
   ```

*I hope I could help.*

I suggest you take a look here for more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts

Comment: Thank you for solution. Some people don't understand how to answer a question. And give negative points to the question. Regards..

Answer (score 3):

You aren't passing a `body` param into your template

```
res.render("template", { body: "Some text" })
```

Comment: actually body is other template so html content. i do not want to send a parameter, just write the file to in main template ('layout')

Comment: @VolkanCoskun it wasn't clear from your question that body was a template you were looking to render inside your layout, so presumed you were looking to pass something from your web server.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

1. Firstly I have changed the file name. template.ejs to layout.ejs.
2. I have changed the `res.render("template")` as `res.render("layout")` in controller.js. Thus, the actual layout was written on the screen.
3. I have wanted write home.ejs to in layout.ejs. Therefore I have changed `<%-body%>` to `<%- include('home.ejs')%>`

Comment: But then this means you have now only one page you can display. The idea of a layout is that it's applied around whatever content template you want. Try `res.render('home')` again, with the original `<%- body %>` but with the renamed file.

Comment: I have shown you I have two files maybe you could not see it ('layout.ejs' and 'home.ejs'). I want to write the file named 'layout'. I have tried your solution but it did not work.

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear. The point of a layout template is that whenever you load another template (e.g. `home`), then the `express-ejs-layouts` library will evaluate that to HTML and then actually render `layout` with the result of the `home` render passed into the `body` argument. It usually doesn't make sense to ever render your layout directly because it's the library's job to do it! So, you would normally write `res.render('home')` and in it would render `layout` automatically with the result of `home` inside of it. Check the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts)

Comment: option 3 worked for me